# Xamarin.Forms Android - tick on virtual keyboard makes screen dim

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with the Android version of Xamarin.Forms app.

When I select a text field, the virtual keyboard appears. Then, if I make a change to the text field's value and press the tick button in the virtual keyboard, the keyboard disappears but also the screen dims. I can un-dim the screen by selecting any textfield again. Also, it doesn't dim the screen if I don't change the text field's value before pressing the tick button.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Did this happen on all the devices or some special device? I can't reproduce the problem.